# Primefaces generating java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/Document on call method to generate PDF for fileDownload

Tags: jsf, pdf, primefaces, itext, jdeveloper

I need your help in solving the issue of not finding the class com/lowagie/text/Document in iText jar. The Primefaces version is 5.0 and the iText version is 2.1.7. The error is generated when I am adding the method name in the actionListner for calling it in order to generate a PDF file from a method and to make it downloadable on the click of a commandButton.

I trued removing all the JARs and adding them one by one and still the issue is the same. All the JARs are unique and I am using Jdeveloper.

The Bean code is:

```
public void createPdf1() {
    com.lowagie.text.Document doc = new com.lowagie.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream in ;
    try {

        PdfWriter writer;

        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);

        doc.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First PDF"));
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        table.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(table);
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "application/pdf", "xxx.pdf");
        System.out.println("INSIDE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the jsf code is which I followed the showcase:

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" actionListner="#{pdf.createPdf1}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{pdf.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

On the click of the commandButton, I am getting the error:

> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/lowagie/text/Document     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:973)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:354)
>     at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:202)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
>   Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.Document
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)

Comment: So, when you let JDeveloper build/export a WAR file based on your project, does the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder contain the iText JAR file of the right version? The exception says it does not.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the hint... In the deployed WAR file the iText is exported, however in my local it is not there. I solved it by placing the JAR in the lin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iText WAR file is kept under the /lib folder and it has worked fine. The compatible version is iText 2.1.7 please refer to the Dependencies in the guide.